# How to use Phabricator only as a code review tool？

Tags: phabricator, github-codereviews

Our team currently uses gitlab as a code repository.
Now we want to integrate a code review tool, but we hope that the code is still submitted directly to gitlab and the Phabricator just use for code review.
What can i do? Are there any related tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to do a pre-commit or post-commit review? ([Review vs Audit](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/reviews_vs_audit/))

If you want an **audit** workflow, you can just [Observe a repository](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_uris/#observe-a-repository).

And if you want **pre-commit**, I suggest you [create a regular Phabricator repo](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/diffusion_hosting/) and setup Gitlab to pull changes from it. It will probably will be most straightforward to do Pull Requests and review/push workflow with Phabricator and Arcanist anyway.